# How do I filter a list using a disclosure group in swiftui

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a DisclosureGroup that is filled from an array and also a list view that is filled from a data struct. In the data struct I have a variable that matches the strings within the array of the DisclosureGroup.

Is there a way that once an option has been selected from the DisclosureGroup, the list is filtered and only displays products that match the option selected from the DisclosureGroup.

I have removed all formatting modifiers and also simplified the productData to keep the code shorter. Thank you in advance.

DisclosureGroup and list view:

```
struct ProductList: View {

@State private var selectedOption = "Option 1"
@State private var isExpanded = false

var options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
var products: [ProductModel] = productData

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        DisclosureGroup("\(selectedOption)", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
            ScrollView{
                VStack{
                    ForEach(options, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item)
                            .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedOption = ("\(item)")
                            withAnimation {
                                self.isExpanded.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        List{
            ForEach(products) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: ProductTabView(product: item)) {
                    ProductListRow(product: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Model Struct

```
struct ProductModel: Identifiable {
     var id = UUID()
     var title: String
     var option: String  
}
```

Data:

```
let productData: [ProductModel] = [
    ProductModel(
        title: "product1",
        option: "Option 1"
    ),
    ProductModel(
        title: "product2",
        option: "Option 2"
    ),
    ProductModel(
        title: "product3",
        option: "Option 1"
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ObservableObject` as a View Model:

```
class ProductListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var products: [ProductModel] = productData

    var options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]

    var selectedOption: String {
        didSet {
            products = productData.filter { $0.option == selectedOption }
        }
    }

    init() {
        selectedOption = options[0]
    }
}

struct ProductList: View {
    @ObservedObject
    private var viewModel = ProductListViewModel()

    @State
    private var isExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DisclosureGroup("\(viewModel.selectedOption)", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.options, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    self.viewModel.selectedOption = ("\(item)")
                                    withAnimation {
                                        self.isExpanded.toggle()
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.products) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProductTabView(product: item)) {
                        ProductListRow(product: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I recommend you [familiarise yourself with MVVM](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4161005-mvvm-with-combine-tutorial-for-ios)

Comment: This is great! Thank you and thanks for the link as well!